# Install a Macro With a Batch File

Tags: vba, batch-file, ms-word

I have a macro for Word that I would like to share with people, I want to create a batch file that installs the macro into word and assign it to a button.

Here is the batch file I have right now:

```
copy "Collapse.dotm" = "%appdata%\Microsoft\Word\STARTUP"
"%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Office\Office15\Winword.exe" /mCollapse
```

First the batch script copies the macro to the Word Startup folder. Then the script launches word, I ran the script and it is telling me it can't copy the macro.

EDIT: The error message was that Word could open up the template, I changed the extension to .dot instead of .dotm. With that change the script runs without errors, the template can be seen in the VBA Editor but doesn't create a macro.

EDIT 2: It creates a new project in the VBA that is unviewable though.

Comment: I suppose the `/m` switch is to specify the path to `Collapse.dotm`, right? if so, you did not provide the extension `.dotm` and neither the full path to the file in your second line; which directory are you running your batch file from??

Comment: You are correct, and right I will add the file extension and see if that helps! And the batch file is running from a folder that's on the desktop.

Comment: Okay... note, that you might need to enclose the path within `""` if it contains spaces...